# Replacing letters at certain indices

Tags: python, string

I'm currently making a hangman program. It starts out and asks you for a letter, and then if you get it right, it replaces a dash at that word, with the letter.

For example:

If the word is jazz, and you choose an a, it would come out

```
-a--
```

now when you guess a z, it's supposed to come out as

```
-azz
```

but instead, it only prints the z at the first index that the letter z shows up.

```
-az-
```

Here's my code so far:

```
secret_word = "jazz"
dashes = "----"


def get_guess():
    while True:
        print dashes
        guess = input("Guess: ")
        if len(guess) > 1:
            print "Your guess must have exactly one character!"
        elif guess.isupper():
            print "Your guess must be a lowercase letter!"
        elif guess.isdigit():
            print "Your guess must be a letter!"
        else:
            return guess
            break


def update_dashes(secret_word, dashes, guess):
    for i in range(len(secret_word)):
        if guess == secret_word[i]:
            #right here is where I change the dashes to letters.
            dashes = dashes[:i] + guess + dashes[i + 1:]
            return dashes




while True:
    user_guess = get_guess()
    dashes = update_dashes(secret_word, dashes, user_guess)
    if user_guess in secret_word:
        print "That letter is in the secret word!"
    else:
        print "That letter is not in the secret word!"
```

Comment: You `return dashes` **inside the `for` loop**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You perform a `return dashes` **inside** the `for` loop (well inside an `if` in the `for` loop). So that means that from the moment the `if` "fires" you will return the result.

You should return **after** the `for` loop:

```
def update_dashes(secret_word, dashes, guess):
    for i in range(len(secret_word)):
        if guess == secret_word[i]:
            dashes = dashes[:i] + guess + dashes[i + 1:]
    return dashes  # for loop ended, all possible replacements done
```

A more Pythonic version is probably to work with `zip` (and use `str.join`):

```
def update_dashes(secret_word, dashes, guess):
    return ''.join(guess if guess == real else old
                   for real, old in zip(secret_word, dashes))
```

Here we iterate in parallel over the `secret_word` and `dashes`. In case the character of `secret_word` (the `real`) is equal to the `guess`, we emit `guess`, otherwise we emit the `old` character. We join then all these characters together in a string.

Answer (score 2):

You have your `indentation` wrong in the `update_dashes` `function`. You want to loop through the entire length of the `secret_word` repeatedly replacing the `characters` and only when you have finished, `return` the `dashes` `string`.

```
def update_dashes(secret_word, dashes, guess):
    for i in range(len(secret_word)):
        if guess == secret_word[i]:
            #right here is where I change the dashes to letters.
            dashes = dashes[:i] + guess + dashes[i + 1:]
    return dashes
```

and just a little *test* in the `interpreter`:

```
>>> update_dashes("bob", "---", "b")
'b-b'
```

which looks like its working great! **:)**